# How to create a test that detect if the page was refreshed?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I want to create a test in ruby that refresh the page and also check if it was refreshed.

```ruby
it 'Refreshing the page' do
  visit current_path
end
```

how to make the assertion of this?

Comment: Are you expecting something on the page to change after refresh?

Comment: No, anything will change after refreshing it.

Comment: This is a strange test without trying to assert on any content on the page to be updated.

Comment: Why do you want to test that a page was refreshed when the content does not change? What is the benefit of such a test?

Comment: Capybara system/feature tests are based on the idea of testing what a user can see on the page - If nothing is changing on the page then you're not going to be able to differentiate between the page before and after refresh and therefore the test is pointless.

Comment: You might try writing to `console.log` at `onLoad`. Your test might be able to read these log entries with `page.driver.browser.manage.logs.get(:browser)` (https://www.joshmcarthur.com/til/2021/04/27/access-browser-console-messages-from-a-capybara-test.html`) Or, you could add some text like "Last updated at ..." to the page.